# How to Get URL of the posted image from unity FB.API() ?

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to share screenshot taken from the app and upload it and share it with the app URL. I can upload the image using FB.API(string query, HTTPMethod method, FacebookDelegate callback, WWWForm formdata) but I also want to share the link with the screenshot and for that I have to use FB.FeedShare() and Feed share needs the URL of the image I have just uploaded. So How do I get the url of the image?

Answer (score 1):

The response of `FB.API(...)` call contains the `ID` of the uploaded screenshot. You can call Graph API with that `ID` to get the required information.

Comment: Would you please show the correct graph api method call as well?